# Why yield is needed as any thread might be moving to ready state even without calling yield method

Tags: java, multithreading, yield

I was reading about yield. It is being told that if a thread is running long and if another thread who is going to run for short time need to wait for long running thread to finish its processing. But my question is as per thread scheduler, no thread will run till its completion in one go. it has to oscillate between running and ready states. so will be the case with long running thread. eventually it will move from running to ready after some time and then will resume its works and this cycle will go on till it completes its job. then what is the role of yield? Is it just a voluntary way of moving to ready state to see if anyone need process time ?

Below is the information from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-concurrency-yield-sleep-and-join-methods/ which could not clear my doubt.

yield(): Suppose there are three threads t1, t2, and t3. Thread t1 gets the processor and starts its execution and thread t2 and t3 are in Ready/Runnable state. Completion time for thread t1 is 5 hour and completion time for t2 is 5 minutes. Since t1 will complete its execution after 5 hours, t2 has to wait for 5 hours to just finish 5 minutes job. In such scenarios where one thread is taking too much time to complete its execution, we need a way to prevent execution of a thread in between if something important is pending. yeild() helps us in doing so.
yield() basically means that the thread is not doing anything particularly important and if any other threads or processes need to be run, they should run. Otherwise, the current thread will continue to run.

Comment: It isn't needed. Most schedulers will time-slice running threads. Any impression you may have got to the contrary is mistaken, or 23 years out of date.

Answer (score 0):

`yield()` says to the Java runtime "You may now proceed with another thread". With current operating systems (like Unix or Windwos) which have native threads and preemptive multitasking, a long running thread will be eventually paused for some time and other threads will be executing. With `yield()` this will possibly happen earlier.

On current environments this functionality is not important in most cases. It is especially useful, if you have only cooperaive multitasking, when there is effectively only one thread and another process can only execute when the current process explictly allows to be paused by calling `yield()`.